# Kак заблокировать путь не просто для файла, а внутри файла?

Tags: php, .htaccess

```
/index.php/en/component/users/
/index.php/en/component/users/?task=user.login
```

Вот эти два пути сайт joomla если просто блочу то 500 ошибка идет если через Directory deny

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^.*[-/]y(\d+)-.*$ index\.php?id=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^y(\d+)-.*$ index\.php?id=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^j(\d+)[-/].*[-/]y(\d+)-.*$ index\.php?id=$1-$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^j(\d+)[-/]y(\d+)[-/].*$ index\.php?id=$1-$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^y(\d+)[-/].*[-/]j(\d+)[-/].*$ index\.php?id=$2-$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^y(\d+)[-/]j(\d+)[-/].*$ index\.php?id=$2-$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^.*[-/]y(\d+)[-/]j(\d+)[-/].*$ index\.php?id=$2-$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^.*[-/]y(\d+)[-/].*[-/]j(\d+)[-/].*$ index\.php?id=$2-$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^.*[-/]j(\d+)[-/].*[-/]y(\d+)[-/].*$ index\.php?id=$1-$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^.*[-/]j(\d+)[-/]y(\d+)[-/].*$ index\.php?id=$1-$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

RewriteRule ^c(\d+)[-/].*[-/]g(\d+)-.*$ index\.php?id=$1-$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^c(\d+)[-/]g(\d+)[-/].*$ index\.php?id=$1-$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^g(\d+)[-/].*[-/]c(\d+)[-/].*$ index\.php?id=$2-$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^g(\d+)[-/]c(\d+)[-/].*$ index\.php?id=$2-$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^.*[-/]g(\d+)[-/]c(\d+)[-/].*$ index\.php?id=$2-$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^.*[-/]g(\d+)[-/].*[-/]c(\d+)[-/].*$ index\.php?id=$2-$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^.*[-/]c(\d+)[-/].*[-/]g(\d+)[-/].*$ index\.php?id=$1-$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^.*[-/]c(\d+)[-/]g(\d+)[-/].*$ index\.php?id=$1-$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]


</IfModule>
```

Вот мой htaccess.
DDos атаки идут по этим двум путям через авторизацию

Comment: Расшифруйте: "Htaccess как заблокировать путь не простой для файла внутри файла?
"

Comment: Как запретить переходить по этим ссылкам/путям?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule (/index.php/(ru|en)/component/users/) [L,R=403]
```

Comment: что то не сработало

Comment: Вверх переместите правило, скорее всего у вас срабатывает уже ваше, которое ранее написаное.